# Read in file contents to Arrays

Tags: python

I am a bit familiar with Python.  I have a file with information that I need to read in a very specific way.  Below is an example...

```
1
6
0.714285714286
0    0    1.00000000000
0    1    0.61356352337
...
-1  -1    0.00000000000
0    0    5.13787636499
0    1    0.97147643932
...
-1  -1    0.00000000000
0    0    5.13787636499
0    1    0.97147643932
...
-1  -1    0.00000000000
0 0 0 0   5.13787636499
0 0 0 1   0.97147643932
....
```

So every file will have this structure (tab delimited).

- The first line must be read in as a variable as well as the second and third lines.
- Next we have four blocks of code separated by a `-1   -1   0.0000000000`.  Each block of code is 'n' lines long.  The first two numbers represent the position/location that the 3rd number in the line is to be inserted in an array.  Only the unique positions are listed (so, position 0 1 would be the same as 1 0 but that information would not be shown).
- Note: The 4th block of code has a 4-index number.

**What I need**

- The first 3 lines read in as unique variables
- Each block of data read into an array using the first 2 (or 4 ) column of numbers as the array index and the 3rd column as the value being inserted into an array.
- Only unique array elements shown.  I need the mirrored position to be filled with the proper value as well (a `0 1` value should also appear in `1 0`).
- The last block would need to be inserted into a 4-dimensional array.

Comment: I had not tried anything (lack of experience with Python) hence my post on SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rewrote the code. Now it's almost what you need. You only need fine tuning.

I decided to leave the old answer - perhaps it would be helpful too.
Because the new is feature-rich enough, and sometimes may not be clear to understand.

```
def the_function(filename):
    """
    returns tuple of list of independent values and list of sparsed arrays as dicts
    e.g. ( [1,2,0.5], [{(0.0):1,(0,1):2},...] )
    on fail prints the reason and returns None:
    e.g. 'failed on text.txt: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.0', line: 5'
    """

    # open file and read content
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            data_txt = [line.split() for line in f]
    # no such file
    except IOError, e:
        print 'fail on open ' + str(e)

    # try to get the first 3 variables
    try:
        vars =[int(data_txt[0][0]), int(data_txt[1][0]), float(data_txt[2][0])]
    except ValueError,e:
        print 'failed on '+filename+': '+str(e)+', somewhere on lines 1-3'
        return

    # now get arrays
    arrays =[dict()]
    for lineidx, item in enumerate(data_txt[3:]):
        try:
            # for 2d array data
            if len(item) == 3:
                i, j = map(int, item[:2])
                val = float(item[-1])
                # check for 'block separator'
                if (i,j,val) == (-1,-1,0.0):
                    # make new array
                    arrays.append(dict())
                else:
                    # update last, existing
                    arrays[-1][(i,j)] = val
            # almost the same for 4d array data
            if len(item) == 5:
                i, j, k, m = map(int, item[:4])
                val = float(item[-1])
                arrays[-1][(i,j,k,m)] = val
        # if value is unparsable like '0.00' for int or 'text'
        except ValueError,e:
            print 'failed on '+filename+': '+str(e)+', line: '+str(lineidx+3)
            return
    return vars, arrays
```

Comment: I can map a float to position (i,j) in the array but not (j,i).  I tried inserting `arrays[-1][(j,i)] = val` into the if/else statement but my array does not double in size at all (21 elements as opposed to the required 42).  Any thoughts?

Comment: Strange. That should work. Did you checked for typo? Cases where i=0, j=0 ?

Answer (score 2):

As i anderstand what did you ask for..

```
# read data from file into list
parsed=[]
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        # # you can exclude separator here with such code (uncomment) (1)
        # # be careful one zero more, one zero less and it wouldn work
        # if line == '-1  -1    0.00000000000':
        #     continue
        parsed.append(line.split())

# a simpler version
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    # # you can exclude separator here with such code (uncomment, replace) (2)
    # parsed = [line.split() for line in f if line != '-1  -1    0.00000000000']
    parsed = [line.split() for line in f]

# at this point 'parsed' is a list of lists of strings.
# [['1'],['6'],['0.714285714286'],['0', '0', '1.00000000000'],['0', '1', '0.61356352337'] .. ]

# ALT 1 -------------------------------
# we do know the len of each data block 

# get the first 3 lines:
head = parsed[:3]

# get the body:
body = parsed[3:-2]

# get the last 2 lines:
tail = parsed[-2:]

# now you can do anything you want with your data
# but remember to convert str to int or float

# first3 as unique:
unique0 = int(head[0][0])
unique1 = int(head[1][0])
unique2 = float(head[2][0])

# cast body:
# check each item of body has 3 inner items
is_correct = all(map(lambda item: len(item)==3, body))
# parse str and cast
if is_correct:
    for i, j, v in body:
        # # you can exclude separator here (uncomment) (3)
        # # * 1. is the same as float(1)
        # if (i,j,v) == (0,0,1.):
        #     # here we skip iteration for line w/ '-1  -1    0.0...'
        #     # but you can place another code that will be executed 
        #     # at the point where block-termination lines appear
        #     continue 

        some_body_cast_function(int(i), int(j), float(v))
else:
    raise Exception('incorrect body')


# cast tail
# check each item of body has 5 inner items
is_correct = all(map(lambda item: len(item)==5, tail))
# parse str and cast
if is_correct:
    for i, j, k, m, v in body: # 'l' is bad index, because similar to 1.
        some_tail_cast_function(int(i), int(j), int(k), int(m), float(v))
else:
    raise Exception('incorrect tail')

# ALT 2 -----------------------------------
# we do NOT know the len of each data block 

# maybe we have some array?
array = dict() # your array may be other type

v1,v2,v2 = parsed[:3]
unique0 = int(v1[0])
unique1 = int(v2[0])
unique2 = float(v3[0])

for item in parsed[3:]:
    if len(item) == 3:
        i,j,v = item
        i = int(i)
        j = int(j)
        v = float(v)

        # # yo can exclude separator here (uncomment) (4)
        # # * 1. is the same as float(1)
        # # logic is the same as in 3rd variant
        # if (i,j,v) == (0,0,1.):
        #     continue

        # do your stuff
        # for example,
        array[(i,j)]=v
        array[(j,i)]=v

    elif len(item) ==5:
        i, j, k, m, v = item
        i = int(i)
        j = int(j)
        k = int(k)
        m = int(m)
        v = float(v)

        # do your stuff

    else:
        raise Exception('unsupported') # or, maybe just 'pass'
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I needed. I forgot to explicitly mention that the `-1 -1 0.00000` lines were simply block-termination lines (iterate though, when reach a value of -1... end current array and start a new one).  I think I may be able to tweak your example to get what I need.  Of course any help is always welcome.

Comment: Added some code insets (4 variants) where you can exclude 'block-termination lines' or process them as you need. Hope you enjoy it!

Comment: I appreciate your continued help.  I'm having trouble telling the program to create a new array everytime a -1 indicator is reached, then populate that array with the following block of code.  Right now it is dumping all blocks of code with a length of 3 elements into one array.

Answer (score 1):

To read lines from a file iteratively, you can use something like:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
  var1 = int(f.next())
  var2 = int(f.next())
  var3 = float(f.next())
  for line in f:
    do some stuff particular to the line we are on...
```

Just create some data structures outside the loop, and fill them in the loop above. To split strings into elements, you can use:

```
>>> "spam   ham".split()
['spam', 'ham']
```

I also think you want to take a look at the `numpy` library for array datastructures, and possible the `SciPy` library for analysis.

Comment: better to use `with open(filename, "r") as f:` and put statements in `with` block

Comment: Edited the answer, I think the main advantage is the fact that `close` does not need to be called on the file connection.

Comment: Sorry, I was sleeping. I edited the answer a bit too quick...corrected in the answer...